# I use computed property (use setter in side) with static keyword ,but report error

Tags: swift

here is my code in swift ,what is the problem,i just want to use computed property with static keyword.

```
class TypeProperty {
  static var Info:String {
    set(str) {
      TypeProperty.Info = str
    }
    get { 
     return "none"
    }
  }
}
TypeProperty.Info = "I am Info" /* here i get error ,what is problem with it */
```

Comment: What error? Runtime or compile-time? Your code won't work because saying `TypeProperty.Info = str` inside the setter just calls the setter recursively. Although what's the point in having a setter if the getter is just going to always return `"none"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is whenever you set Info `TypeProperty.Info = "I am Info"` it will stuck in an infinite loop. It's because you are setting same variable within the setter of that variable.

You can do something like that..

```
class TypeProperty {
    static var _info:String?
    static var Info:String {
        set(str) {
            _info = str
        }
        get {
            return _info ?? "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is mean when i use " = " assign new value for computed property(not stored property ) , the swift will automatically call the setter method for the computed property ? If that , I think  i can understand  what you   say about the “ it will stuck in an infinite loop. ”

Comment: Yes when you use `=` operator  followed by any string it will trigger the setter (`set`)